# PHP Warning: ldap_modify(): Modify: Operation not allowed on RDN

Tags: php, ldap

I have the following code for modifying details in Active Directory:

```
function updateActiveDirectory($user, $first, $last, $mail, $number, $title, $service, $team)
{
$server = "DC-1";
 $unit           = "OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=rugby,DC=internal";
 $ds                = ldap_connect($server);
 if(!$ds)
 {
      return "Cannot connect to LDAP server";
 }
 $bind = ldap_bind($ds, "DOMAIN\Administrator", "PASSWORD");
 if(!$bind)
 {
      return "Couldn't bind to LDAP server";
 }
 ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
 $sr = ldap_search($ds, $unit, "(sAMAccountName={$user})");
 $ent= ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
 $userdata = array();
 $userdata["cn"][0]=$first. " ".$last;
 $userdata["sn"][0]=$last;
 $userdata["mail"][0]=$mail;
 $userdata["telephonenumber"][0]=$number;
 $userdata["company"][0]=$service;
 $userdata["department"][0]=$team;
 $userdata["title"][0]=$title;
 $name = $ent[0]["dn"];
 ldap_modify($ds, $name, $userdata);
}
```

I am getting **Warning:**

> ldap_modify(): Modify: Operation not allowed on RDN

but am not able to find anything online about this issue. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify the `CN` attribute like that. That attribute forms the [RDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx). If you need to modify that you should use the [ldap_rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-rename.php) function:

```
$rdn = 'cn='.ldap_escape($first." ".$last, null, LDAP_ESCAPE_DN);
ldap_rename($ds, $ent[0]["dn"], $rdn, null, true);
```